# How to update YAML file using PyYAML?

Tags: python, azure-devops, yaml, pyyaml, aws-devops

How can I comment the '**driverClassName**' line and update **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount** to 200

In the YAML snippet below, using python (PyYAML package)?

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config: 
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
spring:
  quartz:
  job-store-type: jdbc
  enabled: true
  properties: 
     org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 50
```

Comment: PyYAML cannot comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyYAML cannot add comments. It actually removes all comments on loading, so in general PyYAML
is not the appropriate tool for YAML documents that need further human interaction (which
I assume is the reason for adding a comment).

You should do this with `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config: 
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
spring:
  quartz:
  job-store-type: jdbc
  enabled: true
  properties: 
     org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 50
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['config'].yaml_add_eol_comment('this is the SQL driver', 'driverClassName', column=50)
data['spring']['properties']['org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount'] = 200
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
PRODUCT_HOME: /app
config:
  active-profiles: mysql,oauth2
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver       # this is the SQL driver
  datasourceurl: jdbc:h2:file:./data
  datasourceuser: sa
spring:
  quartz:
  job-store-type: jdbc
  enabled: true
  properties:
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 200
```